# Topology of uniform convergence of functions $X\to X$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, uniform-convergence, uniform-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and that $\phi\colon X\to X$ is a homeomorphism. What does it mean to take the closure of $\{\phi^{k}:k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ with respect to the topology of uniform convergence? Or more generally, what does the the *topology of uniform convergence* look like in this particular case? Since there is no metric involved, I don't know what 'uniform' means in this context. I read something about uniform spaces sitting properly between metric spaces and topological spaces, but it seemed quite technical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X$ is compact Hausdorff so it has a unique uniformity $\mathcal{U}$.
It's convergence in the uniformity on $C(X,X)$ induced by $\mathcal{U}$ that is meant.

i.e. for all open neighbourhoods $O$ of $\{(x,x): x \in X\}=:\Delta_X \subseteq X \times X$ we have
a basic open set $B(f,O)$ for $f \in C(X,X)$ defined by

$$B(f,O):= \{g \in C(X,X)\mid \forall x \in X: (f(x), g(x)) \in O\}$$

and this defines a local base at $f$ in the uniform topology. So now you know $f$ is in the closure of $\{ \phi^k\mid k \in \Bbb Z\}$ iff

$$\forall O \in \mathcal{N}(\Delta_X): \exists k \in \Bbb Z: \forall x \in X: (\phi^k(x), f(x)) \in O$$

This makes it quite concrete.

Comment: +1. I was unaware of this simple fact.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy not everyone knows about uniformities (though a general topologist can really profit from knowledge of it). They've gone out of style.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for your clear answer. Do you have any introductory references for uniform spaces? E.g. a reference that discusses why compact Hausdorff spaces admit a unique uniform structure.

Comment: @Calculix Willard discusses this fact and uniform spaces in general too.