# If the eigenfunctions of $T_{\phi}f:=f\circ\phi$ span $C(X)$, then $\overline{\{\phi^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}^{\text{unif}}$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-spaces, arzela-ascoli

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. We endow $C(X,X)$ with the [topology of uniform convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137436/topology-of-uniform-convergence-of-functions-x-to-x/4137444?noredirect=1#comment8560695_4137444). Let $\phi\colon X\to X$ be a homeomorphism and consider the linear isomorphism $T_{\phi}\colon C(X)\to C(X)$ defined by $T_{\phi}(f):=f\circ\phi$. Suppose that the eigenfunctions of $T_{\phi}$ span $C(X)$, that is,

$$C(X)=\overline{\text{span}\bigcup_{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}}\ker(T-\lambda I)}.$$

I want to show that $\overline{\{\phi^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}}^{\text{unif}}$ is a compact group.

I think there are versions of Arzela-Ascoli that may help, but I am not sure about this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apparently, according to [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-61/issue-1/On-topological-dynamical-systems-with-discrete-spectrum/10.3792/pjaa.61.8.full), there may be a proof in theorem 1 of the following article:

> K. Sakai and S. Horinouchi: On compact transformation groups with discrete
> spectrum. Sci. Rep. Kagoshima Univ., 33, 1-5 (1984).

Unfortunately, I could not find this article online.

Comment: what have you tried? Have you tried arzela-ascoli?

Comment: @supinf I noticed that for eigenfuntions $f$ we have $\{T_{\phi}^{n}(f):n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{f\circ\phi^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\{\lambda^{n}f:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Also, I think that $\{\phi^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is equicontinuous w.r.t. the topology of uniform convergence iff $\{f\circ\phi^{n}:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is equicontinuous in $C(X)$.

Comment: Is it on purpose that you're [linking to a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137436/topology-of-uniform-convergence-of-functions-x-to-x/4137444?noredirect=1#comment8560695_4137444) rather than [to that question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4137436/topology-of-uniform-convergence-of-functions-x-to-x)?